# Automatic tag autofill like on SoundCloud?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, tags, soundcloud, jquery-autocomplete

I want to implement the same system of automatic tag recognition in my Node.Js app: a user types in `#word1 word2` and this is recognized as one tag with two words, not as only one tag.

I know of `jquery.textcomplete` and `jquery.taghandler` but these only can do tags that are one word long. And I need a system that would recognize tags that are phrases, like on SoundCloud:

[image]

Do you know any library that would help me do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here this could be your starting point. 
It just uses jQuery.

You need to add autocomplete, validation, etc.

Press enter to add Tags.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputTags">Tags</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputTags" placeholder="Enter tags">
</div>   
<div id="tags"></div>
```

JS

```
var tag = '';
$("#exampleInputTags").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        tag = '#' + $("#exampleInputTags").val();
         $("#tags").append(tag + '<br/>');
        $("#exampleInputTags").val('');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/b7gju2c1/

EDIT:

I have added some logic for autocomplete. 
RegEx patterns should be tested and changed. 
Dont know how to add this to the input context so far.

JS

```
var tag = '';
var str = 'JavaScript';

$("#exampleInputTags").keyup(function (e) {
    var re = $("#exampleInputTags").val();
    console.log(re);
    if (re != '')
    { 
    testinput(re, str);
    }
    else if (re == '')
    {
    $("#suggestions").text('');
    }
});

function testinput(re, str) {
  if (str.search(re) != -1) {
   $("#suggestions").text(str);
  } 
}

$("#exampleInputTags").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        tag = '#' + $("#exampleInputTags").val();
         $("#tags").append(tag + '<br/>');
        $("#exampleInputTags").val('');
    }
});
```

HTML

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputTags">Tags</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputTags" placeholder="Enter tags">
  </div>      
  <div id="tags"></div>    
      <br/><br/>
   <div id="suggestions"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/yye1b4ye/

If that all does not fit your needs, take a look on the typeahead add on from bootstrap.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead